# adding numbers from and EditText to and TextView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

How can i add numbers from an EditText and then show them in an TextView?

i've tried to convert them but it doesnt work...

```
total = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textView14);
input1 = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.editText1);
input2 = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.editText2);

TextView total;
EditText input1, input2;

int totalScore;
totalScore = Convert.ToInt32(input1) + Convert.ToInt32(input2);

        btnCalc.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            total.Text = Convert.ToString(totalScore);
        };
```

Thanks for helping..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    btnCalc.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
        totalScore = Convert.ToInt32(input1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(input2.Text);
        total.Text = totalScore.ToString();
    };
```